# API for retrieving graph visualization - GraphDB Free

Tags: rest, api, graphdb

I have been exploring the API of GraphDB and I was wondering if there is any command to retrieve a graph visualization of an RDF resource. The people who use graphDB know that in the section `Explore > Visual graph` you can search for a RDF resource and a graph will be displayed.

I do know and have already tested it, that there are certain commands by using `curl` or simply sending HTTP requests, that allow to CRUD SPARQL queries, issue queries, CRUD repositories, etc. Does GraphDB support a rest command to retrieve a graph visualization like it is done in the `Visual graph` previously described?

My idea is to "put myself" in the middle by creating an interface which allows **users** to query the database by using a simple way (eg: with logical AND/OR blocks) rather than having to learn SPARQL.

If you are wondering why I want GraphDB I can tell you that I really like the presentation, and other alternaties, like Neo4J are quite simple when it comes to draw a graph (actually it is muddled and as long as I am concerned, it does not have node expansions as GraphDB).

It would be much appreciated if you could help me!

Comment: Have you checked the Visual Graph feature described at: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/exploring-data.html#explore-resources?

Comment: Sure! But I want to make is kind of like a wrapper. I would like to add some extra functionality like a friendly filter section for "common" users (people with limited understanding about computers). So, the question is simple: can I retrieve from the GraphDB server JUST THE desired graph by sending an HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

Since October 2019, the GraphDB 9.0 Workbench interface is an open-source project. For further information on how to extend the application or extra parts of it, check the detailed instructions in:

https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-workbench